# Is there a way I can close Modal without using the default Buttons on ANTD?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

So I am new to ReactJS and I'm using ANT Design and currently playing around with their Modal. I want to know if we can close the Modal without using the **OK** and **Cancel** buttons.

So I removed these buttons. And created a Button inside the config. I want to close the Modal using that Button. Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Here is my code.

```
const {  Modal, Button  } = antd;

const ReachableContext = React.createContext();
const UnreachableContext = React.createContext();

const handleButtonOnClick = () => {
  console.log('this button was clicked');
}

const config = {
  visible: false,
  title: 'Use Hook!', icon: null,
  okButtonProps: { style: { display: 'none' } },
  // cancelButtonProps: { style: { display: 'none' } },
  content: (
    <div>
      <ReachableContext.Consumer>
        {sample => (
          <Button
            type='primary'
            block
          >
            Click Me Button
            // IS THERE A FUNCTION THAT I CAN CLOSE THE MODAL USING THIS BUTTON?
          </Button>
         )}
      </ReachableContext.Consumer>
    </div>
  ),
};

const App = () => {
  const [modal, contextHolder] = Modal.useModal();
  return (
    <ReachableContext.Provider value={modal}>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          modal.confirm(config);
        }}
      >
        Confirm
      </Button>
      {contextHolder} 
    </ReachableContext.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I close/show the [`Modal`](https://ant.design/components/modal/#header). I don't use `Ok` or `cancel` button. If the prop `showForm` is `true` then Modal will show up otherwise not.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../../actions";

import { Modal, Icon } from "antd";

class FormContainerModal extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    const { showForm } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          title={
            <div>
              Title
            </div>
          }
          destroyOnClose={true}
          footer={null}
          centered
          maskClosable={false}
          onCancel={this.props.closeModal}
          visible={showForm} //it will close the modal if showForm is false
          width="950px"
        >
            <div>
              My Content
            </div>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    showForm: state.form.showForm
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(FormContainerModal);
```

In your case, you can change the boolean value of `showForm` upon button click.

```
           <Button
            type='primary'
            block
           onClick={()=>this.setState({showForm: false})} //here make showForm to false to close the modal
          >
            Close the Modal
          </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you only have one modal open (or don't mind also closing any additional open modals), you can call the class method

```
Modal.destroyAll()
```

from anywhere and it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the destruction of the modal using a button within the modal content like so:

```
const modal = Modal.info();

const closeModal = () => modal.destroy();

modal.update({
  title: 'Updated title',
  content: (
    <Button onClick={closeModal}>Destroy</Button>
  ),
});
```